# How to set pageItem properties in Basil.js?

Tags: extendscript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

This is a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713306/svg-and-extendscript-in-indesign-how-can-i-style-textframes).

How do I set pageItem properties like shearAngle in Basil.js?
In ExtendScript it is:

```
myPageItem.properties = {
    shearAngle:20
};
```

or

```
myPageItem.shearAngle = 20;
```

What would be the Basil.js-ish equivalent?

What about nested properties like some preferences?

```
app.activeDocument.properties = {
    documentPreferences:{
        pageWidth:100,
        pageHeight:100
    }
};
```